How to specify that a function argument is one of the keys of an Interface?
In TypeScript, I want to ensure that the argument to myFunction is one of the keys of MyInterface. That is, I want the type checking on arg specified below.
export interface MyInterface {
  option1: boolean;
  option2: boolean;
  option3: boolean;
  option4: boolean;
}


myFunction(arg: 'option1' | 'option2' | 'option3' | 'option4'): void {
    console.log("arg:",option)
}

I know that I can Type a variable as one of the keys of an Object with let myVar : keyof typeof obj, as described here. Can something similar be done with Interfaces? Is there a way to get the behavior above without hardcoding  'option1' | 'option2' | ...?  I.e., something similar in spirit to arg: in MyInterface.keys?

There's no difference between "keys of an interface" and keys of a general object" in the sense that you write keyof followed by the name of the type. So that's keyof MyInterface or keyof typeof obj.

Yes, you can use the keyof type operator.
function myFunction(arg: keyof MyInterface): void {
  console.log("arg:", arg);
}

Playground link to code
